# How to get pagination response outside thunk react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

How to export total number of products from axios header separately. I want to pass this total in pagination.

```
export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk('products/getProduct', async (params, { dispatch }) => {
    
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.example.com');
    
        var dataChip= response.data;
        return dataChip;
    });
```

There is a total number of products in header.

```
response.headers['content-range'] //Example response: 550
```

Example Result:

```
export const total = 550;
```

Comment: You could set the total value to dataChip object.

Comment: @salix It is not in any class or function.

Comment: after putting the value to dataChip object, you can extract it in a reducer and set to the redux store.